# sso with netsuite integration in spring using cas

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, netsuite

I want to implement Single signon between Spring application and Netsuite using cas. Seached many things on net but nothing was fruitful. kindly help me on this with some links or documents.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just completed two SSO's in NetSuite for our firm. (You will find this under Setup>Integration>SSO) We ended up having NetSuite send a specifically crafted URL to our internal PHP intranet. The web app' there receives the incoming URL and does stuff on it, and the user gets what they need.

Forgive me for not knowing anything about Spring, but  if you can run your web app' to receive an incoming URL (post), then you will create a new SSO object inside of your ERP instance, and pass the values that you need to pass to your web app' from there. Those can be built-in values that come right out the system (ie: "{entityid}") or these can be values that you create with a script, pass them to the SSO, then the SSO passes those to your web app'. You can "place" an SSO "object" on to a "custom Tab" on your "custom Form". Or you can create an entirely new Form. Or you can place your SSO in some other location. I chose to place ours on a custom Tab, as that was effective for our use case.

The only other two places you can "place" your SSO is on to a "Portlet" (say, like a custom panel on your Dashboard or similar) or a "SuiteLet" (which I havent done yet but am working on  right now).

If you have any "bundles" installed in your instance, some of them have SSO inside of them, and some of them are "protected" and some of them are not, and the unprotected ones can be downloaded as JavaScript to your machine for examination, consideration, & emulation.

The help in SuiteAnswers is decent but doesnt give many working examples for your to adapt. The PHP Tool Kit has a working sample of an SSO inside of it & I highly recommend getting that, unzipping it, and reading all of those files, even if it has no table of contents, you can easily follow all the includes and references amongst those files.

If you have a specific follow-up question about something in there, please post, and while I'm an intermediate at it, I'll give it the ole college try to answer. And if you need anything past that, ping me.

Cheers.

Comment: I wanted to add one more thing: NetSuite just released support for SAML. (I am 2/3 through implementation here.) I know that it is not a replacement for SSO, but if it is an alternative for your situation, check it out.